# Error while installing Maven on windows 7

Tags: maven, windows-7

So following the instructions found here http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/ I attempted to set up Maven on a windows 7 environment. Problem is when I ever I run mvn --version or any command with mvn for that matter I get an error saying:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classwords.launcher.Launcher
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look to the [doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/FAQs-1) you can read this:

> **Why do I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/classworlds/Launcher when I try to execute Maven?**
>
> This sometimes happens when $M2_HOME is not the same as your $PATH. That is, when 'which mvn' does not match $M2_HOME/bin/mvn.